# How to avoid app crash when picking a image with flutter and image_picker package?

Tags: flutter

I'm building a application for taking photos and send them into firestore, i'm using image_picker :0.5.0+8 when I'm trying to pick a image from camera or from gallery the app crash. it open gallery very well or the camera very well but if a choose a picture the app crash.

this is my code:

> File image_state;   AppState state;
>
> bool isLoading;   bool isShowSticker;   String _imageUrl;
>
> Future getImage() async {
>       var tempImage = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
>
> ```
> setState(() {
>   image_state = tempImage;
>   state = AppState.picked;
> });
>
> File croppedFile = await ImageCropper.cropImage(
>   sourcePath: image_state.path,
>   ratioX: 1.0,
>   ratioY: 1.0,
>   toolbarTitle: 'Cropper',
>   toolbarColor: Colors.blue,
> );
> if (croppedFile != null) {
>   image_state = croppedFile;
>   setState(() {
>     state = AppState.cropped;
>   });
> }   }
> ```

is there some one who work with this librairy? can you show me an example that work please?

Answer (score 0):

[issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/24463)

There are example of usages inside the plugin's [repo](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/image_picker/example).

It may be related to AndroidX compability. You have to [avoid AndroidX](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility#avoiding-androidx) or [migrate your project to AndroidX](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility#how-to-migrate-a-flutter-app-to-androidx).

There were a breaking change after version [0.5.0](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/image_picker#050)

[image]